# sphinxAPI more than one sort method implementation

Tags: sphinx

while fetching records from sphinxApi , i have used the following sort mode. SetSortMode (SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, " field DESC"). Records need to be display randomly. so i have added the below sort method also. SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "@random");But records display randomly. But records not display based on first sort method. How to implement two sort methods in single query? Please suggest. Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "field DESC, @random");

(Although I dont know for sure if @random can be combined with others. Extended does support multiple sort orders otherwise)

Comment: SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "field DESC, field1 desc"); result coming
SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "field DESC, field1 desc, @random"); retuen emptyset

Comment: Might be worth trying `...desc, @random asc");` ?

Comment: Are you looking at getLastError/getLastwarning?